# what a difference between React function component | class component?

Tags: reactjs

> When I using function component and when I using class component in
> react  because when I work with react.js I can't understand what
> difference because the function and class component is work fine

Comment: Basic explanation - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/differences-between-functional-components-and-class-components-in-react/

Answer (score 1):

Shortly, Class Components:

1. Have their own state to implement some logic to your app;
2. Have Lifecycle methods (`componentDidMount()`, `componentDidUpdate()`, etc);

Functional Components are simple JS functions that accept props and return a React element, without any changes.

[This article might also help](https://www.twilio.com/blog/react-choose-functional-components)

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays the differences of use between class based components and functional ones are very few.

Just a little implementation to what @airblade said:
while class components have a state and Lifecycle methods, from October 2018 (I might be wrong on the date), functional components have the so called hooks: functions that simulate state or Lifecycle methods for functional components.

Personally I only use functional components since I have recently started programming in React and looks like that's where React is heading to.

There's this good article on Medium that explains the use of React Hooks: [React Hooks — How To Use useState and useEffect Example](https://medium.com/@loons.create/react-hooks-how-to-use-usestate-and-useeffect-example-914c161df34d)